# How to access (closed user group) programmatically?

Tags: aem, jcr, crx

I have created Closed User Groupe `My_CUG` in `crx` and added some users `user1` and `user2`. I would like to get the user registered in `My_CUG` and their email. How can I Access `My_CUG` programmatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that in the following way -

If you group name is "My_CUG" then you can resolve the corresponding group object by using the correct admin privileges -

```
 Session adminSession = resourceResolver.adaptTo(Session.class);
 UserManager um = AccessControlUtil.getUserManager(adminSession);   
 Group naGrp = (Group) um.getAuthorizable("My_CUG");
```

Now you can add any user (user1) to this group by -

```
naGrp.addMember(user1_Object);
```

Hope this solves your problem.